# Start a server from event handler in swing

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, server, event-handling

So I am making a application, which starts a server when I press the start button. I am new into networking in Java so the server is very basic. When I try to start the server the application freezes. I know I have to use multi-threading to solve it, but I don't know how to multi-thread. Here is a little code snippet of the event for the start button:

```
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(e.getSource() == startButton) {

                appendToChat("CONSOLE > Trying to start server...");
                server = new Server(4454);

                inputField.setEditable(true);
                stopButton.setEnabled(true);
                startButton.setEnabled(false);
            }
```

And here is the code from the server:

```
public class Server {

private ServerSocket serverSocket;
private Socket socket;
private Scanner scanner;
private PrintStream stream;

private int port;

private boolean succes = false;

public Server(int port) {
    this.port = port;   
    init();
}

public void sendToClient(String value) {
    stream.println(value);
}

public String getMessage() {
    if(scanner == null) {
        return "reader NullPointerException";
    }
    return scanner.nextLine();
}

public int getPort() {
    return port;
}

public void stop() {
    try {
        serverSocket.close();
        socket.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    scanner.close();
    stream.close();
}

public boolean isSucces() {
    return succes;
}

private void init() {
    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        socket = serverSocket.accept();
        scanner = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
        stream = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        succes = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        succes = false;
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are blocking the UI thread in the call to ServerSocket.accept(). You need to call this on a separate thread so that the UI thread can proceed with its operations.

Change your init() method code into an inner Runnable class, and run that in init()

```
private void init() {
  new Thread(new SocketRunner()).start();
}

private class SocketRunner implements Runnabled {
    public void run() {
      try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        socket = serverSocket.accept();
        scanner = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
        stream = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        succes = true;
      } catch (Exception e) {
        succes = false;
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Application freeze because `serverSocket.accept()` waiting for a request in 4454 port. So you have to start your server in different thread. Code update.

```
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() == startButton) {

            appendToChat("CONSOLE > Trying to start server...");

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    server = new Server(4454);
                }
            }).start();


            inputField.setEditable(true);
            stopButton.setEnabled(true);
            startButton.setEnabled(false);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program is freezing because the server starts to listen if there is any client which it can accept. I suggest your `Server` class to extend `Thread`. You will need to implement `run()` function which should contain `init()` method and infinite loop with `getMessage()` function. After creating your `Server` object, you will have to invoke `start()` method.

```
public class Server extends Thread {

    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private Socket socket;
    private Scanner scanner;
    private PrintStream stream;

    private int port;

    private boolean succes = false;

    public Server(int port) {
        this.port = port;   
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        init();
        while(true) {
            getMessage();
        }
    }

    public void sendToClient(String value) {
        stream.println(value);
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        if(scanner == null) {
            return "reader NullPointerException";
        }
        return scanner.nextLine();
    }

    public int getPort() {
        return port;
    }

    public void disconnect() {
        try {
            serverSocket.close();
            socket.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        scanner.close();
        stream.close();
    }

    public boolean isSucces() {
        return succes;
    }

    private void init() {
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
            socket = serverSocket.accept();
            scanner = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
            stream = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            succes = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            succes = false;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And the `actionPerformed()` function:

```
 @Override
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource() == startButton) {

        appendToChat("CONSOLE > Trying to start server...");
        server = new Server(4454);
        server.start();

        inputField.setEditable(true);
        stopButton.setEnabled(true);
        startButton.setEnabled(false);
    }
```